# Any word/phrase for 'what one says' and 'actually does'?

Tags: word-request

Quite common in a politicians' case; is there any word/phrase that describes the **huge** gap of *what they said (too many things)* and *what actually they did (nothing)?* Also, is there any term for **them**, the speakers (boasters?)?

Only one word/phrase please, if any.

Comment: A *chasm* between words and deeds?

Comment: They might be called "snow jobbers".

Comment: @DamkerngT. As a native speaker of English I can honestly say I have *never* heard of someone being called a *snow jobber*.

Comment: @Matt Actually, it's new to me too. The post reminded me "snow job", and while I was looking for its spelling, I found "snow jobber" being used in many places, as a person who did a snow job. So I thought it might be an acceptable slang.

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of words and phrases you can use, but the easiest one is just to call them a **hypocrite**:

> **Hypocrite** (n)
>
> a person who indulges in hypocrisy.

> **Hypocrisy** (n)
>
> The practice of claiming to have moral standards or beliefs to which one's own behavior does not conform; pretense.

Some useful phrases you might like also are:

> *[a **pot**] **calling the kettle black*** (idiom) - someone accusing someone of something that they themselves do
>
> *a **wolf in sheep's clothing*** (idiom) - someone who tricks you into believing that they are one thing when they are in fact the opposite.
>
> a ***fraud*** - someone who is entirely not who they claim to be (*esp*. someone who does so for *criminal* ends)
>
> a ***sham*** - someone who is entirely not who they claim to be (*esp*. someone who pretends to be famous/successful/wealthy but is not).
>
> a ***charlatan*** - somewhat archaic form of *hypocrite*
>
> Someone who is ***duplicitous*** says one thing but does another (*esp.* focus on what they *said* being wrong).
>
> Someone who is ***two-faced*** says one thing but does another (*esp.* with focus on what they *did* being wrong).

With the exception of the idioms, you can add superlatives if you want:

> I found out that Sophie is a ***total fraud***!
>
> I found out that Joseph is a ***massive hypocrite!***
>
> James does *what!?* That's *sickeningly* **duplicitous**.